# How to get rid of space in between nav bar and banner pic?

Tags: html, css

So there's a white space in between the nav bar and the banner image which I want to get rid of but I don't know where it's coming from because I've got margin:0 for the nav bar and banner so how can I get rid of it? Here is my HTML code for it:

```
<div id="nav" style="margin-bottom:0px" >
<p style=" color:#ecad5d; background-color:#fff;margin-left:20px;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px">  <img 
src='images/logo.png ' width="35" height="35" > ARED</p>
<ul>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
     <li style="text-align:right;"><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 12pt;">Services
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="sports.html">Sports</a>
          <a href="events.html">Events</a>
           <a href="">Social media</a>
            <a href="">Medical</a>
        
        </div></div>
       <li style="text-align:right;">  <a href="">Medical</a></li>
     <li style="text-align:right;"> <a href="" >Testmonies</a></li>
     <li style="text-align:right;"> <a href="case study.html" >Case study</a></li>
     <li style="text-align:right;"> <a href="" >Blog & news</a></li>
  <li style="text-align:right;">  <a href="" >Contact us</a></li>
   
</ul>
</div>


<!-- <div id="background"> -->
<section>
    <div id="header3" style="margin-bottom: 10%;margin-top:0px;padding:0px">
        <div id="headertext"><h1>Sports</h1></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is my CSS code for the nav bar and the banner pic:

```
#nav {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
background-color: #D4D4D4;
margin-bottom:0px
}

#nav p {
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: center;
}

#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;


}

#nav li {
float: left;

}

#nav li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
  
}



/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}

.navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #d4d4d4;

}

.navbar a {
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;

}

.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #000;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 115px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
#header3 {
height: 300px;
background-image: url('../images/banner3.jpg');
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: right center;
width: 100%;
}
```

Here is what it looks like : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR1cG.png)

Comment: You can apply padding and margin.

Comment: If you update the question to be a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem, it'll be much easier for us (and for you) to identify the source of that whitespace.  Runnable code is always easier to debug than just a picture of the resulting UI.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the h1 tag containing "sports" has some margin on the top. I changed it so it has `margin: 0` and `padding:0`. I also changed the sports image to a background color of red to demonstrate the effect.

```css
/* Here is the changes i made */
#header3 {
  background-color: red;
}

#headertext h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* End of changes */

#nav {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
background-color: #D4D4D4;
margin-bottom:0px
}

#nav p {
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: center;
}

#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;


}

#nav li {
float: left;

}

#nav li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
  
}



/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}

.navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #d4d4d4;

}

.navbar a {
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;

}

.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #000;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 115px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
#header3 {
height: 300px;
background-image: url('../images/banner3.jpg');
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: right center;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" style="margin-bottom:0px" >
<p style=" color:#ecad5d; background-color:#fff;margin-left:20px;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px">  <img 
src='images/logo.png ' width="35" height="35" > ARED</p>
<ul>
    <li style="text-align:right;"> <a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
     <li style="text-align:right;"><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 12pt;">Services
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="sports.html">Sports</a>
          <a href="events.html">Events</a>
           <a href="">Social media</a>
            <a href="">Medical</a>
        
        </div></div>
       <li style="text-align:right;">  <a href="">Medical</a></li>
     <li style="text-align:right;"> <a href="" >Testmonies</a></li>
     <li style="text-align:right;"> <a href="case study.html" >Case study</a></li>
     <li style="text-align:right;"> <a href="" >Blog & news</a></li>
  <li style="text-align:right;">  <a href="" >Contact us</a></li>
   
</ul>
</div>


<!-- <div id="background"> -->
<section>
    <div id="header3">
        <div id="headertext"><h1>Sports</h1></div>
    </div>
</section>
```